# What does "観終わる" mean here?

Tags: translation

I read a comic where a character is being scolded by her mother for binging tv shows but she says this line which confuses me.

> 大体 全８シーズンある ドラマを鑑賞するとして

(My translation is something like "To begin with, I'm here to appreciate all the 8 seasons of this drama.)

> どうして観終わるまで度を立てるのかしら

The second line I'm definitely confused with. Is "観" separate from "終わる"? I'm also asking about the meaning of "度を立てる". Since it looks like there' different usages of 度.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

観終わる is a compound that means "to watch until the end".

As for the 2nd line, I'll take a stab at it and guess that you confused the kanji of 席 (seat) for 度 (degree).

> どうして観終わるまで席を立てるのかしら

I wonder why you have to keep standing until you
finish watching. (mother's line i suppose?)

Comment: Not my downvote but I think that 席を立てる is "stand up [from the seat]", not "keep standing". though the phrase does sound strange in that case

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B8%AD%E3%82%92%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4

Comment: `I wonder why you have to keep standing until you finish watching. (mother's line i suppose?)` ← Nope, that's not what it means at all, I am afraid.  @Chocolate has the correct answer.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Thanks for the feedback. Chocolate's answer below seems to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

「連用形 (continuative form) of a verb + 終わる」 means "finish doing~~" "complete doing~~" "do ~~ to the end".

e.g.
食べ終わる -- finish eating (≂ 食べ終える)
読み終わる -- finish reading / read to the end (≂ 読み終える)
観終わる -- finish watching / watch to the end (≂ 観終える)

> どうして観終わるまで席を立てるのかしら

It's a rhetorical question (修辞疑問・反語). In the given context it means:

"How can I leave the seat before I finish watching (all the 8 seasons)? (implying: *No, I can't!*)"

<sub>「どうして観終わる**前に**席を立てるのかしら」 might sound more natural, though. 「観終わるまで席を立てる」 sounds unnatural. 「観終わるまで立っていられる」would mean "can keep standing till finish watching". I think they used まで here because of the implied meaning 「観終わるまで席を立てない」(can't leave till I finish) in the rhetorical question. (「～まで...ない」 means "not... until~~".)</sub>